# AUI is not defined and Liferay is not defined error in jsp page?

Tags: liferay, portlet, liferay-6, liferay-theme

I am using my custom portlet in liferay.
but somehow when i run my portlet i m having following error in error console

```
Timestamp: 12/10/2012 12:33:19 PM
Error: ReferenceError: AUI is not defined
Source File: http://localhost:8080/eMenuAdvertise-portlet/js/jquery.min.js
Line: 4

Timestamp: 12/10/2012 12:34:21 PM
Error: ReferenceError: Liferay is not defined
Source File: http://localhost:8080/eMenuAdvertise-portlet/js/jquery.min.js
Line: 3
```

So why this error comes in my jsp page for some jquery?

```
<%@ page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException"  %>
<%@ page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager" %>
<%@ page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager" %>
<%@ page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint" %>
<%@ page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrintManager" %>

<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.model.Role"%>
<%@ include file="/init.jsp"%>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.model.Organization"%>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil"%>
<style>
.borderColor{border: 1px solid #C62626;}
</style>
<portlet:renderURL var="ajaxaddnewrestURL">
    <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/jsps/ajaxnewrest.jsp" />
</portlet:renderURL>
<portlet:renderURL var="editrestURL">
    <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/jsps/Ajax_editrest.jsp" />
</portlet:renderURL>
<portlet:renderURL var="restListURL">
    <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/jsps/rest.jsp" />
</portlet:renderURL>
<portlet:renderURL var="reportURL">
    <portlet:param  name="jspPage" value="/htmlreport/report.html" />   
</portlet:renderURL>
<portlet:renderURL var="renderURL ">
    <portlet:param name="param-name" value="param-value" />

</portlet:renderURL>

<%-- <portlet:resourceURL var="ReportId" id="generate_report"></portlet:resourceURL> --%>
<portlet:resourceURL var="addToDo" id="generate_report"></portlet:resourceURL>  

<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/lib/chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.3/themes/south-street/ui.all.css" type="text/css"> 
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/datepickernew/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/datepickernew/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/lib/chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<%
System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");
System.out.println(java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.isHeadless());

String loading_img_path = request.getContextPath()+"/img/ajax_loader.gif";  
boolean isReseller=false; ///advertiser if flag is false else Reseller
List<Role> role_list_page=themeDisplay.getUser().getRoles();    
for(Role role_name:role_list_page){
    if(role_name.getName().equals("Reseller")){
        isReseller=true;
        break;                                  
    }
}%>         

<script>

</script>



<script>
    $(function() {


        $("#Start_validBeforeDatepicker").datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                $( "#End_validAfterDatepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
                }

        });
        $("#End_validAfterDatepicker").datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                $( "#Start_validBeforeDatepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
                }
        });
       // $("#validBeforeDatepicker").datepicker({ minDate: 0 });
        $('#Start_validBeforeDatepicker,#End_validAfterDatepicker').datepicker();
    });
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(".chzn-select").chosen();
$(".chzn-select-deselect").chosen({
    allow_single_deselect : true
});     
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".ui-datepicker").css("display","none");


    });


    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
function update_rest(addToDo){
    var camp_ID =document.getElementById('camp_id').value;
    var f_start_date =document.getElementById('Start_validBeforeDatepicker').value;
    var f_end_date =document.getElementById('End_validAfterDatepicker').value;






   $.ajax({
        url :addToDo,            
          data: {"rest_name":camp_ID,
              "f_start_date":f_start_date,
              "f_end_date":f_end_date,
              "CMD":camp_ID},
          type: "GET",
          timeout: 20000,
          dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {  
            alert("");
            alert ( " liferay url : "+ Liferay.PortletURL.createRenderURL());
            alert( "row1: " + createRowURL(1) );
            alert( "row2: " + createRowURL(2) );
             $("#mydiv").load("<%=renderURL.toString()%>");
             alert(data);
             }
    });
}



function createRowURL( row ) {
   var portletURL = new Liferay.PortletURL();
   portletURL.setParameter("rowNumber", row );

   return portletURL.toString();
}




function createRenderURL(str) {

        alert("");

        var renderURL = Liferay.PortletURL.createRenderURL();
        alert("hi");
        renderURL .setParameter("jspPage",str);
        renderURL .setPortletId("eMenuAdvertise_WAR_eMenuAdvertiseportlet");
        // i.e. your-unique-portlet-id can be like "helloworld_WAR_helloworldportlet"

}


 </script>



<nav>
    <div id="jCrumbs" class="breadCrumb module">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-home"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Reseller</a></li>
            <li>Restaurants</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
    <div id="successMsg" style='display:none;' class="alert alert-success"></div>
    <div id="errorMsg" style='display:none;' class="alert alert-error"></div>   
        <h3 class="heading">
            Statistics
        </h3>       
        <%String restId = request.getParameter("hide1");%>  
        <portlet:actionURL name="generateReport" var="reportURL"></portlet:actionURL>



    </div>
    <div class="">

        <div class="">
            <div class="">

                <div style="float: right">


                    <p>
                        <label style="width: 100px"><b>Campaign</b></label>
                    </p>
                    <select id="camp_id" name="camp_id"
                        data-placeholder="- Select Restaurants -" class="chzn-select"
                        multiple><%
                        String status = null;                                   
                List<campaign> camp_listObj;
                if(isReseller)
                {                                       
                    camp_listObj= campaignLocalServiceUtil.getAllCampaignByOrganizations(themeDisplay); 
                }
                else
                {
                    camp_listObj = campaignLocalServiceUtil.getAllCampaignByOrganizationId(themeDisplay);
                }
                            for (int i = 0; i < camp_listObj.size(); i++) {
                        %>
                        <option value=<%=camp_listObj.get(i).getPrimaryKey()%>><%=camp_listObj.get(i).getName().toString()%></option>
                        <%
                            }
                        %>
                    </select>
                </div>



                <div style="float: left;">
                    <p>
                        <button onclick="update_rest('<%=addToDo%>');" class="btn btn-success">GenerateReports</button>
                    </p>

                    <b>Start Date</b> <input type="text" style="width: 100px"
                        id="Start_validBeforeDatepicker" name="validTodayDatepicker"
                        readonly="true"> <b>End Date</b> <input type="text"
                        readonly="true" style="width: 100px" id="End_validAfterDatepicker"
                        name="validAfterDatePicker">

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="visibility: hidden;">
                                <input type="hidden" name="report_path" id="report_path" value="">
                            </div>


<%
System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");
System.out.println(java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.isHeadless());

%>


    </div>
</div>
<div class="bordercolor" id="mydiv">

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function editrestaurant(id){

    $(".span12").html("<img class='ajax-loader' src='<%=loading_img_path%>'/>");
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:'<%=editrestURL.toString()%>',
        data:{restId:id},
        success:function(data){
            $(".main_content").html(data);                      

        }
    });
}

function newrestaurant(){   
    $(".span12").html("<img class='ajax-loader' src='<%=loading_img_path%>'/>");
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:'<%=ajaxaddnewrestURL.toString() %>',
        data:{},
        success:function(data){
            $(".main_content").html(data);                      

        }
    });
}


</script>
```

portlet.vm

```
#set ($portlet_display = $portletDisplay)

#set ($portlet_id = $htmlUtil.escapeAttribute($portlet_display.getId()))
#set ($portlet_title = $portlet_display.getTitle())
#set ($portlet_back_url = $htmlUtil.escapeAttribute($portlet_display.getURLBack()))

<section id="portlet_$portlet_id">
        $portlet_display.writeContent($writer)
</section>
```

portal_normal.vm

```
#parse ($init)

<html class="#language("lang.dir")" dir="#language("lang.dir")" lang="$w3c_language_id">

<head>
</head>

<body class="$css_class">

<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="content">
        $theme.wrapPortlet("portlet.vm", $content_include)
    </div>

</div>


</body>

$theme.include($bottom_include)

</html>
```

portal_popup.vm

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

#parse ($init)

<html dir="#language ("lang.dir")" lang="$w3c_language_id">

<head>
    <title>$the_title</title>

    $theme.include($top_head_include)
</head>

<body class="portal-popup $css_class">

$theme.include($content_include)

$theme.include($bottom_ext_include)

</body>

</html>
```

navigation.vm

```
<nav class="$nav_css_class" id="navigation">
    <h1>
        <span>#language("navigation")</span>
    </h1>

    <ul>
        #foreach ($nav_item in $nav_items)
            #if ($nav_item.isSelected())
                <li class="selected">
            #else
                <li>
            #end
                <a href="$nav_item.getURL()" $nav_item.getTarget()><span>$nav_item.icon() $nav_item.getName()</span></a>

                #if ($nav_item.hasChildren())
                    <ul class="child-menu">
                        #foreach ($nav_child in $nav_item.getChildren())
                            #if ($nav_child.isSelected())
                                <li class="selected">
                            #else
                                <li>
                            #end
                                <a href="$nav_child.getURL()" $nav_child.getTarget()>$nav_child.getName()</a>
                            </li>
                        #end
                    </ul>
                #end
            </li>
        #end
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Without seeing the JSP or the project structure how can anyone answer this.
Also what `<script>` elements you have used in the JSP would help. 
Also how you are using Alloy UI or JQuery in the JSP needs to be shown in the question.
So kindly provide more information. Thanks

Comment: please see my updated question for my jsp page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `<script>` you have two javascript functions - `createRowURL` and `createRenderURL` which make use of the Alloy UI scripts as follows:

```js
function createRowURL( row ) {
   var portletURL = new Liferay.PortletURL(); // this is the line using AUI
   portletURL.setParameter("rowNumber", row );

   return portletURL.toString();
}

function createRenderURL(str) {

    alert("");

    var renderURL = Liferay.PortletURL.createRenderURL(); // this is the line using AUI
    alert("hi");
    renderURL .setParameter("jspPage",str);
    renderURL .setPortletId("eMenuAdvertise_WAR_eMenuAdvertiseportlet");
    // i.e. your-unique-portlet-id can be like "helloworld_WAR_helloworldportlet"
}
```

So I would suggest instead of using the `<script> ... </script>` tag use `<aui:script> ... </aui:script>` tags (this loads all the `AUI` and `Liferay` modules), for using this tag you would need to define the taglib in your jsp like:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://alloy.liferay.com/tld/aui" prefix="aui" %>`
```

**Edit** (after seeing the theme templates):

I can see that in your `portal_normal.vm` you have removed the following lines from `<head>` and `<body>` tags respectively:

```
$theme.include($top_head_include) <!-- this statement is removed from <head> -->
$theme.include($body_top_include) <!-- this statement is removed from <body> -->
```

Please include these statements back in the theme templates and your scripts would work. The statement `$theme.include($top_head_include)` this is responsible to include all the `AUI` related stuff (javascripts, functions etc) and also some variables in the request attribute.

**Note**: Please always be careful while removing anything from themes and hooks. You should always know what is the purpose of the statements you are removing or modifying.

Hope this helps.

Comment: one thing i found is its only give error and not working in my custom theme..and if same portlet i use in classic theme then its working.so is there should be mistake in my custom theme?

Comment: i got the main problem is in my custom theme..its not working only when my portlet theme is assigned to my custom portlet but its working fine with the liferay classic theme,,can u suggest whats the problem?

Comment: Without knowing what you have done in your custom theme how can I suggest anything. Still I would suggest look at the changes you have done in your `*.vm` template files in the theme.

Comment: ok..will givng u in my updated question and can we please have some ch8 for this?

Comment: ya...thanx mate..i have that problem.but its just changing my look and feel..if i include that in my .vm file

Comment: thnx for helping me out..atlast done with the problem after changing some css class as per my custom themes